# Li-ion battery IEC 62133 compliance

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, specifications, certification

Hei,

Wondering if any of you have experience on secondary li-ion batteries (not battery packs) that comply with **IEC 62133** certification?

I can't seem to find abundant amount of batteries covering such certification. Can you lead me in a right direction where to buy such batteries?

I have only found this which seems to have passed by IEC 62133:
[Lithium 14500 Rechargeable Cell: 3.7V 800mAh (AA size, 2.96Wh) - IEC62133/UN38.3 Passed](http://www.batteryspace.com/lithium-14500-rechargeable-cell-3-7v-800mah-aa-size-2-96wh---iec62133-un38-3-passed--.aspx)

Capacity should be above 1000mAh and max package 18650.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Farnell site, and look for Varta battery packs. Most of them have IEC 62133 as well as UN38.3 and of course RoHS.

Now the catch. You can buy IEC 62133 cells (not packs), however I assume you are gonna put it to some medical devices. That won't be accepted unless you have a battery protection board (PCM) and a thermistor integrated to the cell.

If you do the integration on your own, you have to re-certify the cell+PCM to IEC62133. This is 4k USD at least.

Therefore it may make sense to actually buy packs, not cells. You may prefer well known brands over some 3rd party panasonic-official-cell-integrator lab in a chinese garage.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.
I've now also used an option, where I ask Directly from the manufacturer, which cells (or in this case full batteries made form these cells) are already certified.